# Firebase Recycler Adapter Indexing problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

here is my database structure :

> Users :
>
> UId1 >> name , age , online
>
> Uid2 >> name , age , online
>
> Friends :
>
> Uid1 >>   Uid4 , Uid3
>
> UId2 >>  Uid4

I used FirebaseRecylceradaptper  with index query

- the indexed query is  `Friends/Uid1`  to get all his friends
- the reference is  `Users`

code here:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
                .setIndexedQuery(Friends/uid1, Users , User.class)
                .build();
```

I get all friends of `Uid1`

but what if i want to get only online friends what should i do farther than that ?

If i use

> Users :
>
> UId1 >> name , age , online ,Friends >> Uid4 , Uid 3 !

How can I get only online friends also ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please kindly take your time to read and understand how to ask question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What should i could explain farther than that for firebase develpers ?

Comment: If you want to show a list of only the friend that are online with the indexed recycler adapter, you will need an index with only the UIDs of the friends who are online. This is quite involved, but I recommend studying the Firebase documentation on building a presence system: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Comment: The problem is not about the presence system .. I have read it .

Comment: Even if want to replace online by an integer value like  " Score " !

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I think I have to do that with making each field like " online " or " score " placed under each friend id like  .. Friends ui1 > ui4 which contains two fields Score - online  and each time those fields changes in the their respective reference I should change them here too .. is that seems right ?